# display seconds counting down in textview Android

Tags: java, android, int, textview, countdowntimer

i have a timer that has a set number of seconds to count down from all the way to 0 so if i put 5 the textview label i want it to show 5,4,3,2,1,0, i already have the timer to stop. i pass in a random number selected by a user so i pass the variable **S** into timer

my textview:

```
 mSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsLabel);
```

my timer:

```
int s = //int taken from on spinner in another class

Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, s * 1000);
```

so when i put `mSeconds.setText(//what should i add here);` to show the number counting down to 0

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338082/how-to-get-value-from-countdowntimer-and-display-into-toast), I think it has what you need

Answer (score 6):

Please check for CountDown Timer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start()
```

Comment: hi sorry i for to mention that im passing in a variable with an that has random int values selected. see question above

Comment: Actually timer work with CPU cycle so it will be make some difference milliseconds you need to print your own counting to show Count Down.

Comment: how would that be possible